# What is the difference between the "Get Flow" and "Get Flow as Admin" action?

Tags: power-automate

I'm trying to set up a flow that backs up all flows in an environment to SharePoint. This is similar to the "Create a file in SharePoint to save modified Flows in JSON format daily" template that Microsoft provides. The difference is I want to backup all flows, not just those owned by an individual.

I expected the "Get Flow as Admin" to return similar data as the "Get Flow" action. However I've found that it returns far less details.

In one case, the "Get Flow as Admin" content-length is 46,856 bytes and the "Get Flow" is 1,245,009 bytes.

The overall structure between the two outputs is similar. The "Get Flow as Admin" has a "definitionSummary" element that includes an "actions" array. The "Get Flow" has a "definition" element that includes an "actions" array, however it contains a lot more details about each action.

I can't find much information online about the difference between these two actions. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: This might be a question for MS support.